# How to integrate a 3rd party class library with Laravel so it autoloads?

Tags: php, laravel, sdk, laravel-4

I am trying to integrate the Temboo SDK with the Laravel framework so that it autoloads like the rest of the vendors.

The SDK has the following structure:

```
temboo
    src
        library
            temboo._23andme.php
            temboo._37signals.php
            etc...
        temboo.php
```

Within the main Temboo file, they have multiple class declarations and each one uses naming such as `class Temboo_Session` and the classes in the `library` dir are of the form `class _23andMe_Names extends Temboo_Choreography`.

The `temboo.php` class file also includes an autoloader class `Temboo_Loader` and declaration `spl_autoload_register(array('Temboo_Loader', 'autoload'));`

This is my first time trying to integrate a non-PSR-0 library, so I am a little lost on this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell Composer to autoload any (non-PSR) class by adding the base folder to:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    ....
```

And you can also autoload autoloaders by adding them to the files section:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "temboo/src/Temboo_Loader.php"
    ],
...
```

After adding those entries, execute

```
composer dumpautoload
```

And check the file `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`, the available classes must be all listed in it, if one file is not there it will not be autoloaded.

Comment: Will the extra autoloader in the Temboo class I mentioned cause any conflicts?

Comment: If those classes have different names, there will be no problem. But having an autoloaded itself, I don't think Composer will understand that it has to call that autoloader, but you can add it to the files section, as my edit shows.

Comment: And having multiple classes in the same base (temboo.php) file won't be a problem either? The autoloader class is a part of the `temboo.php` file, so wouldn't I have to extract that to it's own file first?

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem, Composer will recursively scan all files searching for classes if you have more than one class in one file it should also get that. But having the autoloader togheter with classes might be a problem because you are refering to it twice, in the classmap and the file sections. Composer 'requires' (execute) the files in the files section, so if a class is already autoloaded it might be a (class already exists) problem, or not, you have to test.

Comment: So registering it in composer.json and doing a `composer update` is enough? I don't need to add an entry to `config/app.php` under `providers` in Laravel as well?

Comment: Providers section are for Laravel Service Providers. If the package has one of those and tells you to do it while installing it, yes, you have to add it to `config/app.php`. Is that the case? Looks to me it's not.

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thanks! I actually didn't need to separate out the autoloader class into a separate file.